# how can i play sound when marker is detected in metaio SDK C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, desktop-application, augmented-reality, metaio

I'm newbie in Augmented reality,
I make desktop application using metaio SDK windows.

How to play sound when marker is detected ?
i have using C# sourcode.

i had try, this is my code:

```
public class playsound : monoBehaviour, metaioTracker{
    void Start(){
            if(metaio.trackingvalues=true){
                audio.play();
            }
    }
}
```

but have error like this:

```
Asset/playsound.cs(31,1):error CS8025: Parsing error
```

can anybody help me!!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell, since your code sample does not include line numbers, but I'm betting the problematic line is this one:

```
public class playsound : monoBehaviour, metaioTracker
```

There are two problems with this. First, it's `MonoBehaviour,` not `monoBehaviour.` C# is case-sensitive, and classes, by convention, are almost always CamelCase (with initial capital).

The other problem is that Unity uses an older version of the Mono runtime, which does not support multiple inheritance.

Edit: I should say, does not support multiple inheritance *of concrete classes*. You can inherit from one class and any number of interfaces. This is still a problem in this example, because `metaioTracker` is a class, not an interface.